# Distance Undefined Errors in Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok so I am trying to make a program that goes through a list of subcontractors and their data and then makes a new sheet that is populated with nearby subcontractors.

The issue I am running into is that when the location given for a subcontractor is the same as the job location, an error is returned. Sprecifically: 'TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "".' In the execution transcript of the script editor I get this error right before the code fails.

```
[14-07-11 12:20:29:418 EDT] Maps.newDirectionFinder() [0 seconds]
[14-07-11 12:20:29:418 EDT] DirectionFinder.setOrigin([Louisville, KY]) [0 seconds]
[14-07-11 12:20:29:419 EDT] DirectionFinder.setDestination([3515 Newburg rd, Louisville, KY]) [0 seconds]
[14-07-11 12:20:29:476 EDT] DirectionFinder.getDirections() [0.057 seconds]
[14-07-11 12:20:30:043 EDT] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "". (line 99, file "Code") [6.364 seconds total runtime]
```

In this case is there any way for me to handle this error and simply allow it to pass through? I tried making a dist variable and then setting it equal to 0 if the distance returned undefined, but I am still recieving this error.

The full code of my program is below.

```
/**
 * A shared helper function used to obtain the full set of directions
 * information between two addresses. Uses the Apps Script Maps Service.
 *
 * @param {String} origin The starting address.
 * @param {String} destination The ending address.
 * @return {Object} The directions response object.
 */
function getDirections_(origin, destination) {
  var directionFinder = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  directionFinder.setOrigin(origin);
  directionFinder.setDestination(destination);
  var directions = directionFinder.getDirections();
  if (typeof directions.routes[0] != 'undefined'){
  var dist = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value
  }
  if (dist == 0 && origin == ', ') {
    dist = 100000;
  }
  return directions;
}

/**
 * A special function that runs when the spreadsheet is open, used to add a
 * custom menu to the spreadsheet.
 */
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Find Local Subs', functionName: 'getSubInfo'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Subcontractors', menuItems);
}

/**
 * A custom function that converts meters to miles.
 *
 * @param {Number} meters The distance in meters.
 * @return {Number} The distance in miles.
 */
function metersToMiles(meters) {
  if (typeof meters != 'number') {
    return null;
  }
  return meters / 1000 * 0.621371;
}

/**
 * A custom function that gets the driving distance between two addresses.
 *
 * @param {String} origin The starting address.
 * @param {String} destination The ending address.
 * @return {Number} The distance in meters.
 */
function drivingDistance(origin, destination) {
  var directions = getDirections_(origin, destination);
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}

function drivingDistanceMiles(origin,destination){
  var distMeters = drivingDistance(origin,destination);
  return metersToMiles(distMeters);
}

//start the program and ask for location
function getSubInfo(){
  var job = Browser.inputBox('Job',
                             'Please enter the job name' +
                             ' (for example, "Hamilton WWTP"):',
                             Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (job == 'cancel') {
    return;
  }  
  var jobLocation = Browser.inputBox('Job Site Location',
                                     'Please enter the address of the job site as accurately as possible' +
                                     ' (for example, "2 Rosewood dr, Wilder, Kentucky"):',
                                     Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (jobLocation == 'cancel') {
    return;
  } 
  var maxDistance = Browser.inputBox('Max Distance',
                                     'Please enter a maximum allowable distance from a job site that a sub can be' +
                                     '(for example, "50")',
                                     Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(maxDistance == 'cancel'){
    return
  }
  findSubs(job,jobLocation,maxDistance);
}

function findSubs(job,jobLocation,maxDistance){
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var filteredData = new Array;
  var numFiltered = 0;
  for (row = 0, len = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(); row < len; row++) {
    var subLocation = data[row][26] + ", " + data[row][27];
      if (drivingDistanceMiles(subLocation,jobLocation) < maxDistance){
        for(currentCol = 0; currentCol < 32; currentCol++){
          filteredData[numFiltered][currentCol] = data[row][currentCol];
        }
        numFiltered++;
      }
  }
  buildSubSheet(job,jobLocation,filteredData,numFiltered);
}

function buildSubSheet(job,jobLocation,filteredData,numFiltered){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var infoSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('2012');
  infoSheet.activate();
  var sheetName = job + " Subs";
  var subsSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (directionsSheet) {
    directionsSheet.clear();
    directionsSheet.activate();
  } else {
    directionsSheet =
        spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName, spreadsheet.getNumSheets());
  }
  var sheetTitle = "Subcontractors for " + job;
//  var headers = [
//    [sheetTitle, '', ''],
//    ['Step', 'Distance (Meters)', 'Distance (Miles)']
//  ];
  subsSheet.activate();
  range = subSheet.getRange(2,1,numFiltered,33);
  range.setValues(filteredData);
}
```

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at line 99, where the error is reported:

```
      filteredData[numFiltered][currentCol] = data[row][currentCol];
```

You're assigning a value for an array of arrays (aka a two-dimensional array). At line 93 you defined:

```
  var filteredData = new Array;
```

So you've got an array to start, fine. But before you can assign a value to a sub-array, you need to define IT somehow, first. One way to do that would be within your loop - but since you're indexing by `currentCol`, you should do it within the scope that `currentCol` gets incremented. Something like:

```
  for (row = 0, len = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(); row < len; row++) {
    var subLocation = data[row][26] + ", " + data[row][27];
      if (drivingDistanceMiles(subLocation,jobLocation) < maxDistance){
        filteredData[numFiltered] = new Array;
        ...
```

That will eliminate the error you're getting.

> I tried making a dist variable and then setting it equal to 0 if the
>   distance returned undefined...

Since the bug was elsewhere, you probably didn't need to worry about this. But even so, I hope you don't mind some observations.

```
if (typeof directions.routes[0] != 'undefined'){
```

You're checking for undefined (could check `if (directions.length == 0)` instead, which would be more logical), but then you don't actually set `dist = 0`, so there is a possibility that `dist` will be undefined at the second `if` statement. Since `undefined` and `0` aren't equal, that will evaluate `false`. No error, but it might not be doing what you think it should.

Better to set the default value first, then let calculations proceed:

```
  var dist = 0;   // set the default value first
  if (typeof directions.routes[0] != 'undefined'){
    dist = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value  // no 'var' here
  }
```

When there IS a route, the statement `dist = 100000;` will change `directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value`, which will get `return`ed. That makes sense, since you're trying to disqualify the case where a contractor has given a jobsite as their address. However, when there is no route), setting `dist = 0` will have no effect on the returned `directions` anyway. Instead, you could nest the decisions, and not have to worry about `dist = 0` outside of them.

```
  if (typeof directions.routes.length != 0){  // we have a route
    var dist = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value

    if (dist == 0 && origin == ', ') {
     dist = 100000;   // dest = origin => disqualify
    }
  }
  ...
```